# Windows software that lets me drag and drop clipboard contents?

Tags: windows-7, windows, images, clipboard, drag-and-drop

I use [Prezi](http://prezi.com/).  I'd like to be able to quickly copy an image to my clipboard and paste it into Prezi.  Simply copy pasting doesn't work.  Dragging and dropping an image does.  Is there an application that lets me drag and drop my clipboard contents?  Or, is there a way to paste an image into Prezi?

Comment: Which edition of Prezi are you using?

Comment: I use PreziDesktop3.

Answer (score -1):

https://clipclip.com/features/

> With ClipClip you can select one or multiple Clips and drop them into
>   any folder for safe keeping.

---

**Update**

Drag-and-drop mentioned above is local to app only. (

But it still can be used to move clips to "Saved Clips" folder.

Then files can be dragged from `Documents\ClipClip\Saved Clips` via Windows Explorer.

A bit too much steps, I'd say.